# Counting first letter of title and printing letters from a to z

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to count the titles according to the first letter and filter it by the tag.

I tried for ages and I am not sure if I can write this query in a better way.
Can you please advise me.

Here is the sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3155cd/2

My query:

```
SELECT letter.letter as firstLetter, COUNT(item_tag.id) AS itemCount
        FROM letter
        left outer join item
             on left(item.title, 1) = letter.letter
        left outer join item_tag
            ON item_tag.item_id = item.id
        AND item_tag.tag_id = 1
        GROUP BY letter.letter
```

Here is my tables:

Item:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |      title      |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | title goes here |
+----+-----------------+
```

tag:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | tag name |
+----+----------+
```

item_tag

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | tag_id | item_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

letter:

```
+----+--------+
| id | letter |
+----+--------+
| 1  | A      |
| 2  | B      |
| .  | .      |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle is currently broken again, but you should do the count as early as possible  -> Inner instead of more expensive Outer join and less rows to join.

```
SELECT l.letter AS firstLetter
  -- return 0 for missing letters
  ,Coalesce(lc.cnt,0) AS itemCount
FROM letter AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 ( -- count letters before join
   SELECT Left(i.Title,1) AS letter
     ,Count(*) AS cnt
   FROM item AS i -- no Outer Join needed
   JOIN item_tag AS it
     ON it.item_id = i.id
    AND it.tag_id = 1
   GROUP BY Left(i.Title,1)
 ) AS lc
ON lc.letter = l.letter
```